# Do i need stream hosting to play videos on my website?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

I am planning to launch a website which contains some videos.Do i definitely need a stream hosting to play those videos on my website?

Comment: If you had more experience you would've noticed that there is no "stream hosting". Videos are just plain files. If you have enough bandwidth, you can host them.

Answer (score 4):

No - I'd recommend against hosting the videos yourself directly, as plenty of much more specialized companies will happily do that for you.

Host the videos on YouTube or Vimeo, and embed them in your pages.

Comment: For what it's worth, I profoundly disagree: I wish everyone with video content would host it themselves, as flat files, and let the *user* choose how they'd like to play it.  But I'm well aware that I'm wildly out-of-step with the rest of the world, and I'm sure your advice is best-practice!

Comment: +1 for Vimeo. Forget Youtube though.

Comment: @MadHatter Based on my experience with the average, non-it, user, they would probably end up downloading more RAM if you gave them a choice of how to play a video.